# OpenMP: is there a timeout for a parallel section?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, timeout, scheduled-tasks, openmp

I'm having a problem here with OpenMP. There are two functions that shall be executed in parallel. In `foo()` there's a loop that shall be interrupted with `stop`. And as you can see it is assigned in the the other OMP-section.

The code is:

```
char stop;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
        {
            foo(&stop);
        }
        #pragma omp section
        {
            bar();
            stop = getch();
        }
   }
}
```

and

```
void foo(char *foo) 
{
     while(*stop != 'q')
     {
        // do stuff
     }
}
```

Now what happens when I execute that code: it gets stuck in the first (`foo()`) section. To be more specific in that given loop - which is now an infinite loop, since it never manages to switch to the `bar`section, the break condition can never be adjusted.

Now an easy way out of this would be to timeout the `foo()` section. I searched the internet but couldn't find any applyable code.

Has anyone an idea?

Thanks for any advices!

Comment: Why not add a timed condition to the while loop?

Comment: the sources are stored in a .dll

Comment: Meaning that you have a library that you can't change?

Comment: exactly that's my struggle

Comment: Do you have access to `&stop` from the code calling the dll?

Comment: yes. If I start the program by pressing 'q'. The loop is skipped and the executable finishes. But when != 'q' the loop is executed and can never be leaved again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79544/discussion-between-avi-ginsburg-and-user3085931).

Comment: You should mark the argument of `foo` to be `volatile` in order to prevent the compiler from optimising its use: `void foo (volatile char *stop)`. Also, add a `#pragma omp flush(stop)` after the `getch` statement.

Comment: @HristoIliev, I think this is the first time in a long time that I have heard anyway suggest using `#pragma omp flush`. So it does have some use sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenMP: is there a timeout for a parallel section?

Answer: No.

OpenMP does not have timeouts.

Comment: Thanks I'm looking for a way around then.